# Excel COUNTIFS: Trying to count delinquent dates for tasks that have not been completed

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to count the number of open tasks where the 'Plan' date is before 'Today's date', but does not have an 'Actual Completion Date'. Here is an example of the data I am working with (columns are separated by a comma):

```
Today's Date, 07/23/2013

Item 1, Plan Date, 07/01/2013
Item 1, Expected Completion Date, 08/02/2013
Item 1, Actual Completion Date,
Item 2, Plan Date, 07/01/2013
Item 2, Expected Completion Date, 08/02/2013
Item 2, Actual Completion Date, 12/01/2013
Item 3, Plan Date, 08/23/2013
Item 3, Expected Completion Date, 08/23/2013
Item 3, Actual Completion Date,
```

I tried using the 'COUNTIFS' function within excel to count items that do not have an 'Actual Completion Date', but have a 'Plan Date' prior to 'Today's date' (07/23/2013). In the example data above, I would expect the calculation to return '1' (since only Item 1 satisfies this criteria). However, I have not been successful in creating a 'COUNTIFS' function that would work.

Can anyone help?
I am trying using VBA to solve this problem.

Here is an example of a 'COUNTIFs' function I tried but did not work (returned '0'):

```
=COUNTIFS(B4:B12,"Actual Completion Date",C4:C12,"",B4:B12,"Plan Date",C4:C12,"<"&$C$2)

Column 'B' is for 'Plan Date', 'Expected Completion Date', and 'Actual Completion Date'.
Column 'C' is for dates corresponding to 'Plan Date', 'Expected Completion Date', and 'Actual Completion Date'.
Cell C2 is 'Today's Date' (07/23/2013).
```

Comment: Does EACH item always have 3 lines, and are these lines always in order?

Answer (score 1):

No VBA is required, you can use the *SUMPRODUCT* formula.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$3:$A$11=A17),--($B$3:$B$11=" Plan Date"),--($C$3:$C$11<$B$1))*SUMPRODUCT(--($A$3:$A$11=A17),--($B$3:$B$11=" Actual Completion Date"),--($C$3:$C$11<1))
```

I copied your csv and pasted into a new sheet starting at cell A1. In cells A17-19 I have "Item 1", "Item 2", and "Item 3" respectively, and My formula is in cells B17-19.

There's actually two instances of *SUMPRODUCT* in this formula.

The first checks for rows that contain "Item 1" AND " Plan Date" AND that the date is less than Today's Date in cell B1. Since all criteria are met I get a TRUE value of 1.

The second instance looks for the item AND "Actual Completion Date" AND that there is no date (date<1) in the date column. Since all criteria are met I get a TRUE value of 1.

I then multiply the two results 1*1=1.

I then copy the formula down so it checks items 2 and 3. Item 2 returns a 0 because the second condition fails (there IS a completion date) and item 3 fails because the first condition fails (the start date is later than today's date)

Answer (score 0):

Countifs returns a value if all the conditions are true. In your countifs  B4:B12,"Actual Completion Date" and B4:B12,"Plan Date" can't be true in the same time and that is the problem why you get 0.

In vba you could try this basic code supposing that you always have 3 lines, the order of the 3 dates is the same and you start from the 4th row.

```
Sub check()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, n As Integer, m As Integer, cont As Integer
Set rng = Range("B4:B12")
n = 0
m = 1
For Each cell In rng
    n = n + 1
    If (n = 3 * m) Then
    m = m + 1
         If (Range("D" & 3 + n).Value = "") Then
            If (Range("D" & 3 + n - 2).Value >= "&C2") Then
                cont = cont + 1
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next cell
Debug.Print (cont)
```

End Sub